# What does "nonlocal in time" mean?

Tags: non-locality

I am studying [MOND theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics). At some point Milgrom says the theory needs to be nonlocal in time in order to enjoy Galilei invariance, but I don't understand the meaning. Which are the  major consequences?

Comment: For the record, please provide precise reference for quote.